# SDWebImage downloading but not show image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm using `UICollectionView`.

Images are coming from FTP server.
Here is my code for downloading and Showing image on button :

```
[tempp sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[arrFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ZoomPrdImg"]] //PrdImg //ZoomPrdImg
             placeholderImage:nil
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                        if (image) {
                            myCell.image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [myCell.image setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                [myCell setNeedsLayout];
                            });
                        }
                    }];
```

`myCell.image` is my button that set downloaded image.
Now I don't get that image is successfully dowloaded but nut show in button. There's 3000+ images in `UICollectionView` but it shows some image and some blank.

How this possible ? How to solve this ? What is issue there ?

**EDIT:**
tempp is allocted in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    tempp = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: can u explain what is tempp.image in this line [myCell.image setImage:tempp.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: as i mention in my quen myCell.image is my button that i set downloaded image into it.

Comment: change tempp.image to image when assigning to button

Comment: use placeholder image instead of using `NIL` and make sure your image url is correct.

Comment: I tried this already but it's same issue there.@MuhammadWaqasBhati and @NitinGohel

Comment: what does it mean to use `dispatch_async` in complet block.

Comment: What is tempp? Can you post code where you initiate it?

Comment: tempp allocated in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: And last question where do you call sd_setImageWithURL code?

Comment: in UICollectionView's delegate method cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: See my answer, you call async meth on one object, it is not right method.

Comment: Is you server directory or image file is public? OR do you given permission to access these images for particular user? Is your files are private on server than you can not access it.

Comment: I'm using it with username and password from ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 [myCell.image setImage:tempp.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [myCell setNeedsLayout];
```

with

```
 [myCell.image setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [myCell setNeedsLayout];
```

Because in your completion handler you are getting your image in `image` object

Comment: then check `error` from that completion handler. Because you are not getting image i think

Comment: no there's no error there it downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable tempp is destructed, and cancels request for the image.
Change request code to

```
[myButton sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyURL"] forState:UIControlStateNormal completed:yourCompletitionBlock];
```

And all should be fine.

**UPD**

Based on your answer about tempp variable, I think you see one Image per page, because when  you call sd_setImage... for many cells, only last request is loading. Requests are asynchronous and if you request new image, old request is cancelled.

Code from SDWebImage:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock {
    [self sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageURLKey, url, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

First line cancels old request.

Comment: sd_setImageWithURL is works but it crashes after some time, and exception is : CoreFoundation`CFGetTypeID: -------- how to get rid of this. ?

Comment: I think you is not correct using the method, can you show new code?

Comment: which code ? and im getting image from ftp server so is it making any issues?

Comment: you should't use tempp, use myCell.image. Using of tempp is main mistake, other is not so bad.